# Unable to assign value to an array of an object

Tags: java, android

I have created an array of custom object to store values in it.

```
mNearbyPlaceMini[] mn = new mNearbyPlaceMini[googlePlacesObj.results.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < googlePlacesObj.results.size(); i++) {
    mGooglePlaces.place place = googlePlacesObj.results.get(i);
    Bitmap placeImageBitmap = null;
    try {
        URL imageUrl = new URL(place.icon);
        placeImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mn[i].placePicture = placeImageBitmap; //ERROR HERE
    mn[i].placeName = place.name;
    ...
}
```

But when i try to assign values to the property of an object like this `mn[i].placePicture = placeImageBitmap` it gives me `java.lang.NullPointerException` error. The `placeImageBitmap` has valid values and is not null, so it must be something wrong i am doing with my object array.

```
public class mNearbyPlaceMini {
    public Bitmap placePicture;
    public String placeName;
    public Double latitude;
    public Double longitude;
    public mNearbyPlaceMini(){}
}
```

Comment: can you post your logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign an object to `mn[i]`, so it's null.

You create an array with `mNearbyPlaceMini[] mn = new mNearbyPlaceMini[googlePlacesObj.results.size()];`, but that just creates an array of `googlePlacesObj.results.size()` null objects.

You have to initialize each object in the array with `mn[i] = new mNearbyPlaceMini();`.
Only then you'll be able to access `mn[i]` without getting a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ArrayList<mNearbyPlaceMini> mn = new ArrayList<mNearbyPlaceMini>();
for (int i = 0; i < googlePlacesObj.results.size(); i++) {
                        mGooglePlaces.place place = googlePlacesObj.results.get(i);
                        Bitmap placeImageBitmap = null;
                        try {
                            URL imageUrl = new URL(place.icon);
                            placeImageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageUrl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mNearbyPlaceMini mplaceMini = new mNearbyPlaceMini();
                        mplaceMini.placePicture = placeImageBitmap; //ERROR HERE
                        mplaceMini.placeName = place.name;
                        mn.add(mNearbyPlaceMini);
                    }
```